# I need help on ADO.net

Tags: ado.net, vb.net-2010, sqlclient

Which one is appropriate?

**Methot 1**

```
Dim Connection As New SqlConnection
Dim CMD As New SqlCommand
Connection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
CMD = Connection.CreateCommand()
CMD.Connection.Open()

CMD.CommandText = "Insert Into TableName................."
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
CMD.CommandText = "Update TableName Set................."
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

Connection.Close()
Connection.Dispose()
CMD.Dispose()
```

**Methot 2**

```
Dim Connection As New SqlConnection
Dim CMD As New SqlCommand
Connection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
Connection.Open()
CMD = Connection.CreateCommand()

CMD.CommandText = "Insert Into TableName................."
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
CMD.CommandText = "Update TableName Set................."
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

Connection.Close()
Connection.Dispose()
CMD.Dispose()
```

Both methods are working just fine. But I am confused which one to use. Please help.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Ok... Why do you *think* there's a difference?  Explain what you're asking.  The only thing I see that's different between the two is that you've swapped the lines which create the query object and open the connection.  The order of those two lines by themselves doesn't matter.

Comment: 1.Using command to open a connection
2. Using SQLConnection to open a connection

Comment: Both of those approaches call `.Open()` on the same `SqlConnection` object.  They just do it before or after creating the `SqlCommand` object.  Creating the `SqlCommand` object and opening the connection are not dependent on each other, so the order doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I was confused.
One more thing.
Can I execute several qurey by using one cmd and one sql connection?
Please look at my execution method.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific technical reason that one could *never* do that, but depending on what code you actually end up with it may just be a good idea to keep things separate anyway.  There are a variety of things you could be assuming and not including in the example here.  It's worth trying and seeing if you encounter an actual problem.  One thing to note is that your connection objects shouldn't remain open outside the scope of a single method (unless you really know how to manage connection objects).

Comment: Thanks again. Now I understood. And yes I will not let my connection open outside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by David, there is no functional difference between your two methods.

> Both of those approaches call .Open() on the same SqlConnection
>   object. They just do it before or after creating the SqlCommand
>   object. Creating the SqlCommand object and opening the connection are
>   not dependent on each other, so the order doesn't make a difference.